# In JavaScript when I use the while statement with a prompt, results are unexpected when user clicks "Cancel"

Tags: javascript, while-loop, prompt

I have this piece of code:

```js
function checkGrade(form) {
  var myGrade = parseFloat(form.myText.value);

  while (isNaN(myGrade)) {
    myGrade = prompt("Enter a numerical grade value:", "")
  }

  if (myGrade >= 91) {
    alert("Your grade is an A.");
  } else if (myGrade >= 81 && myGrade <= 90) {
    alert("Your grade is a B.");
  } else {
    alert("Your grade is a C or lower.");
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>CIW JavaScript Specialist</h3>
<hr />
<form name="myForm">
  Enter numerical grade value:
  <input type="text" name="myText" size="10" />
  <p>
    <input type="button" value="Check Grade" onclick="checkGrade(this.form);" />
  </p>
</form>
```

The expected results is that when the user inputs a letter rather than a number, the prompt will ask repeatedly for the user to enter a number. This works when I enter a letter on the prompt box and I click "OK", the same prompt appears again. However, when I put "Cancel" on the prompt, an alert saying "Your grade is C or lower" appears.

How can I fix this? Am I meant to put the parseInt() somewhere?

Pd:I am aware that what I am trying to do is not good practice but I am doing it to understand better how JavaScript works.

Comment: on cancel prompt returns `null` and that's why you get that message ( which by the looks of your code is the default 'alert' string ) . `Return Value: A String. If the user clicks "OK", the input value is returned. If the user clicks "cancel", null is returned. If the user clicks OK without entering any text, an empty string is returned.` from prompt DOCS. So, what would be your expected ' cancel '  behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not accounting for "Cancel"

On cancel, the variable becomes null. So use this:

> if (myGrade === null)

To check if the user hit cancel.

Basically:

```
    if (myGrade !== null)
{
   if(myGrade >= 91) {
alert("Your grade is an A.");
 }
  else if(myGrade >= 81 && myGrade <= 90) { 
alert("Your grade is a B.");
 }
       else {
      alert("Your grade is a C or lower.");
 }
}
```